# Issue with my function using associative array (dom objects) and for loop

Tags: javascript

**Knowledge:** First week Javascript

I am trying to learn real javascript and avoid jquery at all cost. Now I am I recently learned that id's can be style easily but not classes. In order to style a class I need to loop through the dom for the class. My original code works, however my new one does not. Best practices aside for a moment, I am trying to learn how this works regardless if it is a perfect solution or not.

**Problem specifics**: In my new code I stored the two get functions in keys within an associative array. So I have objects which I would like my for loop to understand. I am trying to make it work like my first code.

**What I tried**: Honestly, I read something about squared bracket notation and how it can be useful. I felt a bit overwhelmed to be honest. What I tried was:

```
source[_class][i]
```

Maybe _class is undefined even though I defined it. I specified what class contains. Honestly im lost and would appreciate some help and of course I welcome best practice advice as well.

I want to be a better programmer and I would appreciate some insight. I dont want to start with jquery.

My experiment:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var source = {_id: document.getElementById('box'),
                  _class: document.getElementsByClassName('hint')};

    for (var i = 0; i < source[_class].length; i++) {
        source[_class + i].style.opacity = '0';
        console.log(i);
    }
}, 1000);
```

---

My original working code:

```
// setTimeout(function() {
//  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('hint');

//  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
//      divs[i].style.opacity = '0';
//      console.log(i);
//  }
// }, 1000);
```

Comment: Look in your browser's console for errors.  If all you have is the code shown then the variable named `_class` is indeed undefined.

Comment: @dsh my console says it is not defined

Comment: However, the element exists in my dom

Comment: `_class` in `source[_class]` refers to an undefined variable. You need to write it as `source._class` or `source["_class"]`.

Comment: @Daniel_L That is called dotted notation if im not mistaken

Comment: _"I am trying to learn real javascript and avoid jquery at all cost."_ It's good to know the basics of JavaScript, but I wouldn't recommend avoiding jQuery at all costs--it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: You don't have an element `_class` in your DOM, nor do you have that variable defined.  You have a variable named `source` with an attribute named `_class` that refers to a (list of?) DOM elements. Daniel_L's comment is correct. Or you can define a variable: `var spam = "_class"; console.log( source[spam] );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `source._class.length` instead of `source[_class].length` and `source._class[i]` instead of `source[_class + i]`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < source._class.length; i++) {
    source._class[i].style.opacity = '0';
    console.log(i);
}
```

`source` is an object and has a *property* `_class`. You can access properties either as `source._class` or as `source['_class']`.

The property `source._class` is an collection of DOM nodes itself so it can be accessed like an *array*. You can access array elements like this: `array[index]`.

So you have both an *object with properties* and an *array with elements*. You need to access their contents appropriately.

Comment: so it was a syntax issue but the main idea is correct right? I mean I was on the right track?

Comment: @Asperger Well, you are not wrong, but you could just have used two different variables instead of the `source` object. Additionally, you could assign classes to these elements instead of styling them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a square bracket and it's text not a variable:

```
source[_class + i].style.opacity = '0';
```

should be

```
source["_class"][i].style.opacity = '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Styling should be done with css, not loops, because using css is an order of magnitude faster.

Create css class definitions for your set of styles and then simply change the name of the class on your elements to change their style.

Also, look into using css selectors to query the DOM. This is done with `querySelector` for a single element, or `querySelectorAll` for a set of elements. Note that jQuery wraps this functionality and that is where the name is derived.

For your specific example, the problem was with accessing the array, instead of adding the `i` index, you need to reference the array, and you also need to make sure you are using a string index or a dot notation (such as source._class) in order to reference that object's property

```
for (var i = 0; i < source['_class'].length; i++) {
    source['_class'][i].style.opacity = '0';
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: `source[_class]` is no valid way to access `source._class`. Use either `source._class` or `source['_class']`.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that. Really, there are several issues with using that snippet aside from the simple syntax errors.